# What contact email addresses are more likely to lower the amount of spam that you will receive?

Tags: email, spam

I am wondering if you can obtain a significant decrease in the amount of spam you receive by choosing a "special" email address for contact.

Examples:

- `office@`, `support@`, `contact@` - probably high likely to get more spam due to "dictionary" spam
- `postmaster@`
- `nospam@`
- `robot@`
- `abuse@`
- `webmaster@` - probably a good source of SEO spam
- `noreply@` - probably doesn't make sense

This question refers only to the email name, other methods are not subject of this question. Just assume that they are already implemented (ex. no plain email in web pages, ...).

Pleas mind that it doesn't make sense to generate a hard to type or spell email address, because this will make difficult to give the address to the customers via de phone.

Comment: Come on, reopen it. Isn't the admin the one creating the email addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who knows what evil lurks in the hearts of spammers?  Mwah-ha-ha-ha-ha-ha-ha!

Seriously, who can guess what tricks they'll come up with?  I'd think any "real" word email address will get spam, including all the ones you mentioned.  Offhand, I think the best you could do for a hard-to-spam email address is to have a fairly simple name concatenated to some sort of serial number, e.g.  sorin4376@yourdomain.com *and change the serial number* every so often.

Comment: Is not about getting "no spam, just for lowing the amount you'll get. I did not statistics on this but I think that someting like "postmaster" or "abuse" could be removed from the spammers databases? Is there any mass spammer here that could give us a hint? ;)

Comment: Are you going to put your contact email anywhere on the web? If so, then it doesn't matter if you choose jskdn78232@example.com - you will, eventually, sooner rather than later, get spam on it.